# What do Homura's runes in Rebellion say?

Tags: madoka-magica

Well, if you saw the third Madoka movie, then you know that…

> Homura turns into a witch at some point of the movie.

Knowing that, I'm trying to decipher what her runes say:

[image: clean image 1]

[image: clean image 2]

Some runes are pretty obvious and others not so much:

[image: puzzle]

This is the rune map that I use; it's from the [wiki](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Deciphering_the_runes).

[image: rune-to-Latin map]

As far as I could get, this says something like:

> H O M _ U
>
> H O M _   LILLY

At least, that last part is pretty clear. Any suggestions about the meaning of this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's been confirmed by [multiple](http://archive.foolz.us/a/search/image/4fSjjtKHolpH-Rz0isv4Qg/) sources (from the movie and game) that it says:

> HOMU
>
> LILLY
>
> HOMULILLY

Which matches up with the PSP game:

[image: Homu Homu]

Comment: Her witch form has appear in other media, before the third movie?

Comment: Yes, a [PSP game](http://wiki.puella-magi.net/Madoka_Magica_Portable).